# Not able to drag scrollview object in interface builder

Tags: xcode4, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I'm using XCode 4.6 and interface builder. I've got a UIViewController in interface builder, and a UIScrollView on top within the UIViewController. The scroll view completely spans the view controller (actually, it's taller than the view controller, it has height that is below the bottom of the view controller). This has been working for sometime, but I just ran into a problem. Somehow, I can no longer grasp the scroll view to drag it and reposition it. I click on the scroll view in IB or within the outline but the "hand" icon will not appear to enable movement and repositioning of the scroll view. Ideas?

I'd really rather not re-create all the detailed views within the scroll view. Perhaps this is why some people have a negative attitude about IB? Loosing work because of silly problems that stop you dead.

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved this now. I believe there was supposed to be three layers: (from top to bottom; top towards user) scroll view, view (*), and view controller. Somehow I lost the view in the middle (*) and this was not letting me resize the scroll view.